# How to change top-level scope variables in AngularJS nested controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On a page, I have the following structure:

- layoutController (in the js controller: $scope.currentProject = "" )

  - {{ currentProject.Name }}
  - projectListController - (in the js controller, I populate the value of $scope.currentProject with an object)

The problem is that once I set the new value, {{ currentProject.Name }} remains blank.

What's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a property in the $scope at a parent level it gets inherited through the prototype chain, if you redefine that property in a child $scope you lose that reference.

So the way to proceed would be in projectListController instead of assigning the object to currentProject you should copy the properties into it. Or assign the object to $scope.$parent.currentProject.

Answer (score 2):

use `$parent.value` to access the parent controller scope.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/vj0kUoiXEqH9w5OPNhsu?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You should try and default the value to a blank object like this

```
$scope.currentProject = ""
```

To

```
$scope.currentProject = {}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is because child controllers create a copy of the parent scope.

In your nested controller, you should inject $rootScope instead of $scope

Comment: You don't want to pollute the $rootScope with this, so best to use $parent.

Comment: I know. Ideally you want to use directives with isolated scopes but that's not part of the question.
Using $parent is very sketchy because you would be binding your projectListController to your layoutController.